# Second Order Low Pass Filter, replacing inductor with VCCS and Capacitor

Tags: filter, ltspice, simulation, bandwidth, passive-filter

My instructor told us that we can replace an inductor in the following way.

[image: Realization of Inductor as Capacitor]

Now, I want to construct a second order low pass filter using Voltage Controlled Current Source, Capacitor, Resistor of bandwidth 10 kHz.

So this is the circuit that I made:

[image: Normal RLC low pass filter]

Then I tried to replace the inductor as following:

[image: Replaced inductor as in image 1]

But this has a bandwidth close to 19.95 kHz.

However, when I use values of capacitor such that they differ by a large magnitude, it works fine:

[image: Works when both capacitance differs by a large magnitude]

I have put in so much time, that I can't even figure out where I am wrong.

More importantly, how these values are coming? I found out my own values for simple RLC filter, but when I use them in modified RC, VCCS filter they don't work.

Please help me decide how can I make its bandwidth of 10 kHz, and maximize the gain (small R), only by realizing inductor using VCCS and capacitors.

Comment: I don't think you can do a series inductor with a gyrator.  What happens if you swap the inductor & capacitor locations in your filter?  That way the inductor is a shunt, which is what the gyrator can duplicate.  Check this reference out:  https://sound-au.com/articles/gyrator-filters.htm

Comment: @SteKulov It can be done: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRE0e.png (feel free to add the answer).